# Regression Method for a Survey Repeatedly Asking the Effects of Various Policies

Tags: regression, survey, social-science

I have survey results where I repeatedly asked the respondents about the effects of various policies.

The questions are as follows: "Let's assume you went back to the time when you were a high school student. If the following policy was implemented during your high school years, what would have been your intention to enroll in a sports-related major?
(Note: The sample consists of college students who are not currently enrolled in a sports-related major, and the question is multiple-choice.)

Question1. Policy A: Upon confirmation of enrollment in a sports-related major, an immediate payment of $10,000.
(1) Definitely would not have enrolled in a sports-related major
(2) The policy would have had a positive impact on my decision to enroll
(3) Definitely would have enrolled in a sports-related major

Question2. Policy B: During enrollment in a sports-related major, a scholarship of $1,500 would be given every semester.
(1) Definitely would not have enrolled in a sports-related major
(2) The policy would have had a positive impact on my decision to enroll
(3) Definitely would have enrolled in a sports-related major

Question3. Policy C: A guaranteed one-year study abroad opportunity at a prestigious foreign university for those enrolling in a sports-related major.
(1) Definitely would not have enrolled in a sports-related major
(2) The policy would have had a positive impact on my decision to enroll
(3) Definitely would have enrolled in a sports-related major

The current data is structured as follows:

| id | policyA | policyB | policyC | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 23 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 22 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 20 |

The research interest is to quantify the effect of each policy on the intention to enroll in a sports-related major. In this case, what regression analysis method would be appropriate?